# Execute SQL file using Doctrine Import

Tags: unit-testing, doctrine

I have an SQL script I intend on using as a data fixture while running my unit tests. I understand that the Doctrine DBAL has an import command for the CLI, but I'm only interested in running this from within my unit test scripts.

Based on

```
\Doctrine\DBAL\Tools\Console\Command\ImportCommand
```

I'm struggling to understand how I can achieve this purely from PHP, without using exec if I can help it.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Looking into ImportCommand's code, you can extract its essential part to create your own function:

```php
protected function executeSqlFile(Connection $conn, $file)
{
    $sql = file_get_contents($file);
    $lines = 0;

    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute();

    do {
        // Required due to "MySQL has gone away!" issue
        $stmt->fetch();
        $stmt->closeCursor();

        $lines++;
    } while ($stmt->nextRowset());

    return $lines;
}
```